Visualize geometry in pinhole camera model when tilting the camera
For a pinhole camera I can calculate the image scale at some point and use that to get the real life distance of some distance in the image by using $$-\frac{y_P}{Y_O} = \frac{\Delta x_P}{\Delta X_P}$$
Where $y_p$ is the vertical position of two points in the image and $Y_O$ is the camera height.
I want to use this to calculate the metric width of some horizontal distance on the ground (the camera is assumed to be mounted parallel to the ground).
When tilting becomes involved the tilting angle needs to be accounted for. So I found this modification in a paper:
$$\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta X} = -\frac{y_P \cdot \cos \alpha + c \cdot \sin \alpha}{Y_O} $$
Now I understand that $c \cdot \sin \alpha$ calculates the shift of the horizon line in the image and $y_p \cdot \cos \alpha$ the new distance of the point in the image to the horizon after tilting.
I tried to visualize this to really understand that geometry, but I am having a very hard time doing that.
Visualization attempt
Here $c$ is the camera constant. But things don't add up at all for me. First if I draw it like this, the shifted horizon is not $c \cdot \sin \alpha$ but $c \cdot \tan \alpha$. Second I cannot find where the right triangle forms that allows $y_p \cdot \cos \alpha$ to be calculated as the new distance of the point from the horizon in the image. Maybe I made some fundamental mistake attempting to visualize it like this? I hope someone can point me to the right direction.
